# Cordova InAppBrowser is blank on iPad iOS 10

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

This issue happens only on iPad with iOS 10.

When I try to use InAppBrowser with `presentationstyle` set to `fullscreen` , it pops up fine but when I tap on the Done button, I got a blank screen. Looks like it doesn't destroy itself properly.

I am using Cordova 6.4.0 and InAppBrowser plugin 1.6.1

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is applicable to you but I was also having an issue with a blank screen after tapping the Done button, but it was only happening in landscape. Still worth a shot though:

`cordova-plugin-statusbar` & `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` apparently don't play nice together so try either deleting `cordova-plugin-statusbar` all together or add an event listener on exit:

```
openUrl(url) {
  let ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options);

  ref.addEventListener('exit', () => {
    StatusBar.hide();
    StatusBar.show();
  })
}
```

`StatusBar.hide()` is what fixed the issue for me.

**EDIT**: As noted by René, a blank column exists with the fix noted above. In order to completely fix the issue in both iPhone and iPad without having to remove the plugin, wrap the `StatusBar.show()` call inside a setTimeout of a second:

```
openUrl(url) {
  let ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options);

  ref.addEventListener('exit', () => {
    StatusBar.hide();

    setTimeout( () => {
      StatusBar.show();
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

Thanks René!

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also had to wrap the `StatusBar.show();` call inside a `setTimeout` of a second because calling it during the hiding animation of the inappbrowser didn't completely remove the blank view but a blank column to the right remained visible. Calling show() after the animation finished fixed this.